# Can I Snapshot a SKNode?

Tags: objective-c, swift, uiimage, sprite-kit

I have a SKScene and I want to snapshot a specific layer. It can be a layer displayed on a white UIView with a SKView in it. But in the end I want to take a snap from the state of this layer only.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKView/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/SKView/textureFromNode:

Comment: @LearnCocos2D Thanks, found the answer on the docs. .textureFromNode() is the method that can do the trick.

Answer (score -1):

That's what worked for me:

```
    var tempView = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 500, 500))
    var tempSKView = SKView(frame: tempView.frame)
    var tempScene = SKScene(size: tempSKView.bounds.size)

    var lineTexture = SKTexture()
    lineTexture = skView.textureFromNode(scene.lineLayer)

    var lineLayerCopy = SKSpriteNode(texture: lineTexture)
    lineLayerCopy.anchorPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: 0.0)
    lineLayerCopy.size = CGSizeMake(500, 500)
    tempScene.addChild(lineLayerCopy)
    tempScene.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    tempSKView.presentScene(tempScene)
    tempView.addSubview(tempSKView)
    self.view.addSubview(tempView)
```

Note: the anchorPoint is essential. It forces the scene to position in the center and so you have the perfect image.